# Dual boot mac mini 2012 partitioning

Tags: linux, dual-boot, ios

I have an old mac mini 2012 which has installed iOS on a 500gb ssd, I've shrunk the partition to give space to install Red Hat, so 250gb for iOS in one partition and 250gb for red hat. Ive flashed a usb drive with Red Hat, when I boot up to  choose the storage drive, I get an error "Failed to find a suitable stage device; apple EFI Boot Partition cannot be of type efi. And wont let me install red hat.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

[image]